# How to load array bitmap display in View Pager?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have array of bitmap in my `Activity`. I want to load that array bitmap in to `ViewPager`. I don't have nay idea for this concept.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652482/xamarin-android-bitmap-drawables-to-int-array-for-viewpager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[check this link](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.nl/2012/10/viewpager-example-in-android.html)
you only have to change from drawable to bitmap.. 
here is the code..

Step 1) After creating a fresh project. change your main.xml to as follow so that it have one Viewpager widget in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Step 2) Now our main concern is to bind data inside a Viewpager so that you can easily swipe. PagerAdapter bind the data to Viewpager and create view dynamically when needed. In PagerAdapter we remove the view as soon as its use is over so that we can avoid memory wastage . So create one new class and paste below code inside it.

```
package com.horizontalscrollviewwithpageindicator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

 Activity activity;
 int imageArray[];

 public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra) {
  imageArray = imgArra;
  activity = act;
 }

 public int getCount() {
  return imageArray.length;
 }

 public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
  ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);
  view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
  view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
  view.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[position]);
  ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
  return view;
 }

 @Override
 public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
  ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
  return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
 }

 @Override
 public Parcelable saveState() {
  return null;
 }
}
```

Step 3) This is the final step and Viewpager complete. As in PagerAdapter , i have created one ImageView to display as child of Viewpager so we need one image array to show image. I have image in my drawable folder. I created one array like this

```
private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.antartica1, R.drawable.antartica2,
       R.drawable.antartica3, R.drawable.antartica4,
       R.drawable.antartica5, R.drawable.antartica6,
       R.drawable.antartica7, R.drawable.antartica8 };
```

Now we just need to attach our PagerAdapter to android Viewpager . So we will change our main activity code to as following ---

```
package com.horizontalscrollviewwithpageindicator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
    public class PageIndicatorActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
      ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
      myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
      myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
     }

     private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.antartica1, R.drawable.antartica2,
       R.drawable.antartica3, R.drawable.antartica4,
       R.drawable.antartica5, R.drawable.antartica6,
       R.drawable.antartica7, R.drawable.antartica8 };

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
      return true;
     }

    }
```